# Grab dynamic image and clone/ copy it to another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

I have the function working if I put in the attual src of the image. I am dynamically pulling all the images from api. The issue I am having is I need to somehow clone/ read the image id thats in the dyamic so that it will post the correct picture on the right in the box if you run this code no it just does the one im in.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript" rel="script" type="script" href="script.jss"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js'></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

      var webaddress = '<img id= "[index]" src="http://pokeapi.co/media/img/[index].png">';
      var pokelist = $('#pokelist');               // get your pokelist

      for (var i = 1; i <= 152; i++) {
        var image = webaddress.replace(/\[index\]/g, i);  // escape your square brackets and make it a global replace
        pokelist.append(image);                           // append it to div
      }
    });
    $(document).on("click", '#pokelist', 'img', function () {
      $("#deck1").append('<img src="http://pokeapi.co/media/img/1.png">');
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
  </div>
  <div id="pokedeck">
    <div id="pokelist">
    </div>
    <div id="deck1"></div>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
$(document).on("click", '#pokelist img', function() {
      $("#deck1").append("<img src='"+this.src+"'>");
});
```

Inside the callback function, `this` refers to the image that was clicked.

Comment: This worked as soon as it lets me ill check it right. Ty

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nr0mxqs2/) with the working code:

```
$("#pokelist > img").on("click", function() {
    $("#deck1").append("<img src='" + $(this).attr("src") + "'>");
});
```